# How to iterate rows in excel workbook to scrape URLs?

Tags: python, excel

I'm new to python scripting and have a small problem. Please help with the below issue:
How to iterate the rows so that the keywords will be equal to the names in column 1 and how to write the output to the same excel sheet?

Thank you.

Excel sheet:

```
Col 1

Name1

Name2

Name3
```

Couldnt get the old code to work so here is the new one.

New url_scraper.py script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlrd
import xlwt
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

book = xlrd.open_workbook("test.xlsx")
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
aa = sh.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=0)
df5 = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df5.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, startcol=0)
print (df5)
#df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
df3=df5['aa'] = "http://www.example.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords="+ df5.aa.astype(str)
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, startcol=2, header=False, startrow=1)
print (df3)

book = xlrd.open_workbook("test1.xlsx")
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
row = 1
col = 2
aa1 = sh.cell_value(rowx=row, colx=col)
row += 1
url = aa1
response = requests.get(url)
page = str(BeautifulSoup(response.content))
start_quote = page.find("http://ecx.")
end_quote = page.find(".jpg", start_quote + 1)
url1 = page[start_quote + 0: end_quote + 4]
print (url1)
ds = pd.Series(data = url1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data = ds)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, startcol=1, header=False, startrow=1)
```

Output of new code is as desired, however im unable to loop.

output new code:

col1         col2

name1        url starting with "http://ecx" of name1

name2        url not printing here

name3        url not printing here

Please help.

Comment: To read the column of name strings from your excel file, simplest way may be to use `xlrd`, try the quickstart code: https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd. then assign those values to keywords to pass to your url

Comment: thank you. I will check that

Comment: welcome, if you have any questions implementing or applying it to your code let us know :)

Comment: @downshift., i have updated the code and still facing the same problem. Unable to go cell by cell to download URLs. Please help

Comment: The updated code above. Im able to iterate and print URL's for all the names in rows. However unable to write them on to an excel sheet. Any pointers to fix this??

Comment: My mistake, @Shri, I misunderstood that you wanted to *write* an excel document, I should have pointed you towards [xlwt](https://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but looks like you are already using it. Check if the example in my answer will help to do it.

Comment: Is it possible to read and write in the same excel document? I have tried the one that you mentioned below, but each letter is printed vertically on each cell and only the first row value is being used, not iterating on all rows, any walkaround to that?

Comment: @downshift, i have modified the old code to use pandas which seems to be working, just not able to loop for all values. Any idea to fix this?

Comment: Ok, your second script using pandas looks good. With no data I can't reproduce your output or the dataframe, but maybe you can use [xlsxwriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io) there is a simple example http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_simple.html

Comment: I can get it to write on the excel. But the problem is i cannot get it to loop and output is not printing on the terminal as well

Comment: it's not looping because you don't have any loop commands, usually you need a `for`-loop or a `while`-loop but you don't have either. Also, are you still using the code you posted in the question? Because those print statements `print (df5)`, `print (df3)`, `print (url1)` should print output to your terminal, but they are not printing?

Comment: Can you print and share the contents of `print (df5)`, `print (df3)`, and `print (url1)` so I can try to reproduce what you're getting, and possibly get it working?

Comment: Output on the terminal for print (df5), print (df3), and print (url1) are as below:
df5
Col 1:
Name1
name2
name3

df3:
http://www.example.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=name1
http://www.example.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=name2
name3

url1:
http://ecx.images-example.com/images/I/4wrfetbrtbL._AC_US218_.jpg

Comment: for name 2 and 3 its not printing on the terminal nor in the excel

Comment: cannot embed pictures here since i don't have 10 rep points. hope the above comment of the output makes sense

Comment: I'm sorry, the formatting is not clear and I'm too confused what the problem is, I wish I could help more.

Comment: the problem is im unable to loop over each cell and print the output